# Bicubic Interpolation for Non-regular grids?

Tags: grid, interpolation, bicubic, non-uniform-distribution

I am working on a project where I have a set of known measurements (x,y,z,a) and an input (z,a). I need to be able to interpolate the (x,y,z) so that I can get a list of possible (x,y) coordinates from a given z.

I was looking at bicubic interpolation, but I can only find examples pertaining to regular grids, and my (x,y) pairs are most certainly not regular.

Basically I am looking for some guidance on algorithms/models to achieve this goal. I am considering a triangulated irregular network, which is attractive because it breaks down into planes which are easy to determine the (x,y) from a given Z. But I would like a little more finesse.

I know it sounds like homework, its not.

Efficiency is not a concern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually ended up using Delauney Triangulation to break down the fields into 3 dimensional X,Y,Z surfaces with an Identifier. Then given a set of (Identity,Z) pairs I form a field line from each surface, and from these lines compute the polygon formed from the shortest edges between lines. This gives me an area of potential x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).
These first take a set of scattered points in 2d or 3d or 10d,
then answers queries like "find the 3 points nearest P".

Are your queries `z a` pairs ?
For example, given a bunch of colored pins on a map, a table of `x y size color`,
one could put all the `[x y]` in a kd tree, then ask for pins near a given `x0 y0`.
Or, one could put all the `[size color[` in a tree, then ask for pins with a similar size and color.
(Note that most kd-tree implementations use the Euclidean metric,
so sqrt( (size - size2)^2 + (color - color2)^2 ) should make sense.)

In Python, I highly recommend [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html).

See also SO [questions/tagged/kdtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kdtree) .

Comment: This could prove helpful, I basically will be gathering data like [x, y, size, identifier] and then, given a set of (size, identifier) pairs : get similar (x, y) pairs. I'll take a look and let you know how it turns out, thanks! Hmm, many gears just started turning, double thanks!

Comment: Scale sizes and ids to about the same range, so that sqrt( (size - size2)^2 + (id - id2)^2 ) makes sense. And print the nearest say 3 xy s to the (size, id) s, and make sure *they* make sense.